# React Native Reanimated not working (in Expo app)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

Animations simply aren't happening. I've created a very simple [example repo](https://github.com/benhsampson/animation-problem) to demonstrate this. The demo contains a button that should change the width of the rectangle above it when pressed, but it's not working.

[image: App Screenshot]

I've tested the app in the Android Studio emulator and on a physical device but it fails on both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using Reanimated, you should import 'Animated' from 'react-native-reanimated', in your code you're importing it from 'react-native'. So, correcting your imports:

```
import { Button, View } from "react-native";
import Animated, {
  useAnimatedStyle,
  useSharedValue,
  withTiming,
} from "react-native-reanimated";
//...
```